# Aligning custom button with the Inno Setup Cancel button

Tags: inno-setup, pascalscript

I ve got problems to set a button on the same topsize as the *Cancel* button when im using `WizardSizePercent = 150` in the `Setup` section.

Here is my code:

```pascal
AboutButton := TNewButton.Create(WizardForm);
AboutButton.Parent := WizardForm;
AboutButton.Left := WizardForm.CancelButton.Left;
AboutButton.Top := WizardForm.CancelButton.Top;
AboutButton.Width := WizardForm.CancelButton.Width;
AboutButton.Height := WizardForm.CancelButton.Height;
```

I think Inno Setup doesn't notice the `WizardSizePercent`, because it only uses the regular `WizardForm` size.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I assume your code is in [`InitializeWizard`](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=scriptevents&anchor=InitializeWizard). That event function occurs before `WizardSizePercent` is applied. If you want your button to correctly align when the wizard window changes size, either due to [`WizardSizePercent`](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=setup_wizardsizepercent) or [`WizardResizable`](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=setup_wizardresizable), you need follow their documentation:

> Use `Anchors` and `KeepSizeY` properties to add full support for `WizardResizable` and `WizardSizePercent` to all your custom controls, custom wizard pages and `TSetupForm` forms if you have any. See the *CodeClasses.iss* example script for an example.

So particularly:

```pascal
AboutButton.Anchors := WizardForm.CancelButton.Anchors;
```

`CancelButton.Anchors` is `[akRight, akBottom]`. If your *"About"* button should be left-aligned, use:

```pascal
AboutButton.Anchors := [akLeft, akBottom];
```

---

Related question:
[Adding a Print button to the License page in Inno Setup (revisited for Inno Setup 6)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/69403271/850848)